# CodeIgniter: Passing array from form to controller then to model to insert into database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I've got a form in a view. The following row can be duplicated over and over allowing the client to add as many trashcans as they wish: https://gist.github.com/886337

The problem starts when I try to get the array from $invoice_item

If I have just one line item:

I've tried `$invoice_items = $this->input->post('$invoice_item');`

but if I do `var_dump($invoice_items);` to see what I have I get `bool(false)`

So, I tried: `$invoice_items = array($this->input->post('$invoice_item'));`

and again `var_dump` gives me this: `array(1) { [0]=> bool(false) }`

And then I've tried other things like adding `[]` after `$invoice_items` or `$invoice_item` but nothing seems to work. I just don't know what I'm doing?

Any help would be appreciated because I am lost!

Comment: Always fall back to the userguide when you have issues, it is very detailed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should get your post variable like

```
$invoice_items = $this->input->post('invoice_item');
```

(there is no $ sign)

Comment: and here is a link to the user guide http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html I <3 CI.

Comment: Oh what a day I've had. I can't believe I didn't see that. This afternoon my car's fuel pump went out and I had to figure out a new way to get to Utah next week for a conference. My inlaws came by to visit, and everything's just going crazy. I can't believe I didn't catch that. I just thought I was missing something more complicated. I found another place where I had a stupid mistake. Good thing I stopped when I did to go watch Battlestar Galactica. Who knows what damage I would have caused. Thanks for your help!